# How to force audio output to HDMI/3.5mm jack on RPi4 B via CLI?

Tags: audio, alsa, audio-playback

on RPi 3 we are using something like `amixer cset numid=3 1` and then `alsactl store` to force sound output to jack 3.5mm and store configuration.
I want same thing on my *RPi4 model B*, but it does not work.
I found a few articles like [this](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/rpi4-ubuntu-mate-audio.html) one and it seems that procedure should be very same also for RPi3.
But even the output of `aplay -l` is different in my case:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: b1 [bcm2835 HDMI 1], device 0: bcm2835 HDMI 1 [bcm2835 HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 4/4
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
card 1: Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones], device 0: bcm2835 Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones]
  Subdevices: 4/4
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
```

Also `amixer cset numid=3 1` does not work either:

```
amixer: Cannot find the given element from control default
```

UPDATE: Adding more info:

```
$sudo amixer controls
numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='HDMI Playback Switch'
numid=1,iface=MIXER,name='HDMI Playback Volume'
```

How can I change audio ouput on the fly from CLI as we need it for a script?

Comment: can u give output of `sudo amixer controls`

Comment: @thomachan I updated my question.

Comment: as per https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/latest-raspberry-pi-os-update-may-2020/ , there is no amixer command to change the sound output, as we can see from the amixer controls also. you have to use .asoundrc file